# Performing Calculations From A Pandas Data Frame with Multiple Conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Forgive the question as I'm a science major, not computer science and I'm teaching myself Python to help with a class project.

I have a Pandas data frame that I've imported from a .csv that looks like:

```
Item_ID Event_ID    Value
27  83531   2533501.8
28  83531   1616262
31  83531   269829
32  83531   55.8
33  83531   269829
34  83531   4882
35  83531   269829
36  83531   4882
37  83531   55.8
38  83531   55.8
27  83532   7137904.8
28  83532   5873877.6
31  83532   497381
32  83532   55.7
33  83532   497381
34  83532   7568
35  83532   497381
36  83532   7568
37  83532   55.7
38  83532   55.7
```

This data is from a manual entry that is done multiple times daily where the Item_ID is type of measurement, Event_ID is the unique identifier for each "data entry event" by the user, and value is the value of the measurement.

I need to perform a number of calculations on each unique Event_Id.

```
Calc1 = ([28]/[27])*(([31]*[32])/[28])*(([33]-[34])/[33])
Calc2 = [36]/[35]
Calc3 = ([35]-[113])/[35]
Calc4 = [37]
Calc5 = [38]
```

Each number in the above formula represents an Item_ID.  I want the replace the Item_ID in the formula with the value from the same row for each Event_ID.

This project was started a month ago and will run for 6 more weeks.  By then, there will be to many data points to perform the calculations by hand.

As these calculations cannot be performed across Event_IDs, the formula for Event_ID 85831 would look like:

```
Calc1_Data = ([1616262]/[2533501.8])*(([269829]*[55.8])/[1616262])*(([269829]-[4882])/[269829])
Calc2_Data = [4882]/[269829]
Calc3_Data = ([497381]-[0])/[497381]) ***0 would be placed hear as Item_ID 113 does not exist for this 
              Event_ID
Calc4_Data = [55.7]
Calc5_Data = [55.7]
```

The results would then be put into a new data frame that I could then perform my analysis on.

```
Event_ID Clac1_Result Calc2_Result Calc3_Result Calc4_Result Calc5_Result
85829
85830
85331     RESULTS HERE  
85332     RESULTS HERE  
85833
85834
```

This is my first go at asking a question here since I've been able to find all of my other answers in the library docs or previously asked questions.  If I didn't provide enough information let me know and I'll clarify if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` followed by `agg` methods to do that.

First, define your calculations as functions:

```
# Define calculations
def Calc1(x):
    return (x[28]/x[27])*((x[31]*x[32])/x[28])*((x[33]-x[34])/x[33])
def Calc2(x):
    return x[36]/x[35]
# Calc3 = lambda x: (x[35]-x[113])/x[35] # commenting out because there's no 113 in the provided example
def Calc4(x):
    return x[37]
def Calc5(x):
    return x[38]
```

Then, perform the calculations using the `groupby` and `agg`:

```
df = df.set_index('Item_ID') # set 'Item_ID' to index so that we can use fewer code inside the functions
df = df.groupby('Event_ID').agg([Calc1, Calc2, Calc4, Calc5]) # group by Event_ID, and perform the set of specified calculations
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0) # reset column names
```

Output:

```
             Calc1     Calc2  Calc4  Calc5
Event_ID                                  
83531     5.835418  0.018093   55.8   55.8
83532     3.822212  0.015216   55.7   55.7
```

Comment: Thanks, can you help me understand how the function knows the argument x[28] is referencing the 'Value' column?  I've been reading on lambda functions but I'm not understanding how this works.  How would I reference the Value column if there were more columns in this data set?

Comment: It's referencing to the 'Value' column because there is just that column in the dataframe. If the data has more columns, you can still apply the function in the Value column by specifying the column with: `df.groupby('Event_ID').agg({'Value': my_calculations})` or `df.groupby('Event_ID').Value.agg(my_calculations)`, otherwise it will apply the calculations to each column.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.  Now I understand it.

Comment: When using a function in the `agg` method (instead of `apply`), you can ref a specified index by using `x[idx]` where x is the function name (which means, the group), and `idx` is the index. When using defined functions in `agg` method, think about `x` as being the column in the group. Also, it's important to be familiar with the idea of [split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html) from pandas.

Comment: Okay, so in `def Calc1(x):`  Pandas is interpreting "x" to be the data frame's index?  Then by assigning the Item_ID column as the index, it uses x as a reference for the numbers in the calculations.  Where in `x[36]/x[37]`, it is referencing the 36 or 36 as the indexed row for the grouped set.  Or am I way off here?

Comment: No, "x" is the group column. 36 and 37 are the index (that we set as indexes in `df.set_index('Item_ID')`. But the followed logic is correct.